# In Java, why using generic on an inner class doesn't work?

Tags: java, generics, types

My compiler is JDK 6.0_65, and following are my codes (Deque.java):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    private class Node {
        Item value;
        Node next;        
    }

    public Deque(){}                  // construct an empty deque

    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
        return new DequeIterator<Item>();
    } 

    private class DequeIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
        private Node current = first;
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.next != null;
        }
        public Item next() {
            Item item = current.value;
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }
        public void remove() {}

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)   {         
      // unit testing
        Deque<Integer> dq = new Deque<Integer>();

    }

}
```

In the outer scope :

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
```

is used.

And in the inner scope:

```
private class DequeIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
```

is used.

In the scope of `DequeIterator`. I expected the local-scope (inner-class-scope) `Item` will shadow the class-scope `Item` from `Deque<Item>`.

However, during compiling stage, `javac` will throw an error like this:

```
Deque.java:2: error: incompatible types
            Item item = current.value;
                               ^
  required: Item#2
  found:    Item#1
  where Item#1,Item#2 are type-variables:
    Item#1 extends Object declared in class Deque
    Item#2 extends Object declared in class Deque.DequeIterator
```

It says `Item#2` and `Item#1` is incompatible types, which looks quite confusing to me because I have passed the type parameter `Item` into `DequeIterator` using `new DequeIterator<Item>()`.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: `Deque` is a class name (well, an interface) already used by the JDK; it is not a very good idea to reuse that...

Comment: Just as Node is not parametrised with (a new) Item do not introduce a new Item here, or else rename it. Remove the `<Item>` from DequeueIterator there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I expected the local-scope (inner-class-scope) `Item` will shadow the class-scope Item from `Deque<Item>`

This is basically precisely what happened - the inner-scope `Item` shadowed the outer one. It does not matter that you've passed the outer `Item` to the constructor. The inner class has problems compiling because you're trying to assign a value of type outer-`Item` to a variable of type inner-`Item`.

To fix this just make the nested class non-generic:

```
private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item>
```

In that way you will use the outer-`Item` without declaring another `Item` type parameter which you don't really need.

Answer (score 3):

Yes inner class generic `Item` shadows generic enclosing class `Item`, this is exactly why the compiler complains. You wrote `Item item=current.value` (and that is the problem). Here `Item` refers to the generic type of the inner class, but `current.value` is of generic type `Item` of the enclosing class. These types are different! The compiler named them `Item#1` and `Item#2`. You just have to remove the genericity from inner class `DequeIterator`:

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private static class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that `Item#1` and `Item#2` will *always* be the same. You could add a method like this to `Deque`:

```
public Iterator<Integer> boom() { 
    return new DequeIterator<Integer>();
}
```

This obviously doesn't make any sense, but since the `Item`s of the iterator class aren't related to the enclosing class' `Item`s (because the inner `Item` type parameter shadows the outer) it's perfectly legal.

There's no reason for you to give the DequeIterator class a type parameter though, you can simply declare it thus:

```
private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    // Content remains unchanged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and you may even remove the `<T>`:

```
private class DequeIterator<T> implements Iterator<Item> {
    ...
}
```

I think the problem is some sort of shadowing problem where the inner and outer `Item` are considered different.